# Dynamically created buttons won't fire events in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dynamically creating buttons inside of a dynamically created table. For some reason the button events are not firing. I was wondering if I have to add the events on `init` because I need the Session data to create the table and the buttons along with it. I already tried taking the customer id from the login page and putting it in the URL and using that to do the create table method, but it did not work.

```
for (int i = populate.getBeginCount(); i < populate.getEndCount(); i++)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    DataRow dr1 = QueryHandler.GetDataRow("SELECT * FROM [order_line] WHERE order_id=" + Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i].Field<long>(1)) + ";", CommandType.Text);
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                    switch (j)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            HyperLink Order = new HyperLink();
                            Order.Text = dt.Rows[i].Field<long>(1).ToString();
                            Order.NavigateUrl = "/customer-portal/orderdetails.aspx?partnerid=" + dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(18);
                            tc.Controls.Add(Order);
                            tc.ToolTip = dt.Rows[i].Field<long>(1).ToString();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(21);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            product pro = new product();
                            if (pro.GetProduct(dr1.Field<int>(3), customerId))
                                tc.Text = pro.product_type;
                            else
                                tc.Text = "empty";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            product prod = new product();
                            if (prod.GetProduct(dr1.Field<int>(3), customerId))
                                tc.Text = prod.company;
                            else
                                tc.Text = "empty";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(3);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            DropDownList drop = new DropDownList();
                            ListItem act = new ListItem();
                            act.Text = "ACTION";
                            ListItem Reissue = new ListItem();
                            Reissue.Text = "Reissue";
                            ListItem cancel = new ListItem();
                            cancel.Text = "Cancel";
                            drop.Items.Add(act);
                            drop.Items.Add(Reissue);
                            if (dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(3) == "PENDING")
                                drop.Items.Add(cancel);
                            Button go = new Button();
                            go.Text = "Go";
                            go.ID = "ButtonGo" + i;
                            go.Click += new System.EventHandler(goButton_Click);                           
                            go.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-default filter-cancel";
                            go.DataBind();
                            tc.Controls.Add(drop);
                            tc.Controls.Add(go);
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i].Field<DateTime?>(16).ToString();
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i].Field<DateTime?>(17).ToString();
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            Button b = new Button();
                            b.Text = "View";
                            b.Click += new System.EventHandler(viewButton_OnClick);
                            b.ID = "Button" + i;
                            b.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-default filter-cancel";
                            tc.Controls.Add(b);
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            Button c = new Button();
                            c.Text = "Print Receipt";
                            c.Click += new System.EventHandler(printButton_OnClick);
                            c.ID = "PrintButton" + i;
                            c.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-default filter-cancel";
                            tc.Controls.Add(c);
                            break;
                    }
                    if (tc.Text != "")
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    else if (tc.Text == "" && j == 6)
                    {
                        tc.Text = "Not Completed";
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    }
                    else if (tc.Text == "" && j == 7)
                    {
                        tc.Text = "No Expiration Date";
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    }
                    else if (tc.Controls.Count > 0)
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                }
                Tableorders.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
```

Edit: Here are the goButton_Click() and viewButton_OnClick() methods.

```
 protected void goButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dr = new DropDownList();
        Button b = new Button();
        b = sender as Button;
        dr = (DropDownList)b.Parent.Controls[0];
        //INPUT BUSINESS LOGIC HERE
        if (dr.Text == "ACTION")
        {

        }
        else if (dr.Text == "Reissue")
        {
            TableRow tr = (TableRow)b.Parent.Parent;
            long orderId = Convert.ToInt64(tr.Cells[0].ToolTip);
            DataRow datar = QueryHandler.GetDataRow("SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].[order] WHERE order_id=" + orderId + ";", CommandType.Text);
            string partnerId = datar.Field<string>(18);
            Response.Redirect("/customer-portal/orderreissue.aspx?partnerid=" + partnerId);
        }
        else if (dr.Text == "Cancel")
        {
            TableRow tr = (TableRow)b.Parent.Parent;
            long orderId = Convert.ToInt64(tr.Cells[0].ToolTip);
            DataRow datar = QueryHandler.GetDataRow("SELECT * FROM [Secure128Test].[dbo].[order] WHERE order_id=" + orderId + ";", CommandType.Text);
            string partnerId = datar.Field<string>(18);
            Response.Redirect("/customer-portal/CancelOrder.aspx?partnerid=" + partnerId);
        }
    }

    protected void viewButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b = sender as Button;
        TableRow tr = (TableRow)b.Parent.Parent;
        long orderID = Convert.ToInt64(tr.Cells[0].ToolTip);
        DataRow dr = QueryHandler.GetDataRow("SELECT * FROM [database].[dbo].[order] WHERE order_id=" + orderID + ";", CommandType.Text);
        string partnerid = dr.Field<string>(18);
        Response.Redirect("/customer-portal/orderdetails.aspx?partnerid=" + partnerid);
    }
```

Comment: What does your viewButton_OnClick/goButton_OnClick methods look like?

Comment: Aside: You don't need to `new Button()` in the click methods just to throw away the instance on the next line.